# Is the memory layout actual or virtual?

Tags: computer-architecture

In many computer architecture books (e.g. Computer Organization and Design), the memory layout that is *seen* by a program is as the following figure.

[image]

But I wonder about multitask computers, in which many programs execute simultaneously, how the memory layout is. Is the layout actual or simulated for each program?

Comment: The processes see their own virtual address space. They can coexist in the same, private, virtual address ranges, while being mapped to distinct physical addresses, transparently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory